# база данных не удаляет запись

Tags: java, android, база-данных, sqlite

Удаляю запись с базы данных таким образом (по id):

```
public void removeMovie(Movie movie){
    String[] whereArg  = {String.valueOf(movie.getId())};
    mDatabase.delete(MOVIE_TABLE_NAME, ID + "=? ", whereArg);
}
```

В результате ничего не происходит, запись остается в базе.

Comment: Что за объект `mDatabase`

Comment: @zTrap, SQLiteDatabase mDatabasse https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: может так попробуй : String[] whereArg  = { Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(movie.getId()))};  mDatabase.delete(MOVIE_TABLE_NAME, ID + " = ", whereArg);

Comment: что то странное тут происходит :   mDatabase.delete(MOVIE_TABLE_NAME, ID + "=? ", whereArg);   у тебя whereArg переменная это и есть id который надо удалить ? если да , то тут "=?" не нужен уже "?"  просто попробуй " = " поставить

Comment: А что метод `delete()` возвращает? Если 0, то значит ваше условие не совпало и записи с переданным id в базе нет.

Comment: @eugeneek, как вы и заметили метод возвращает 0. Как такое может быть?Запись в базе точно есть.

Comment: Проверьте название поля `ID`, что точно совпадает с тем полем в таблице, по которому вы ищете элемент. И что сам `id` из `(movie.getId()` тот, что нужно. Скорее всего где-то банальная опечатка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так и не смог понять где моя ошибка. В документации для метода `delete` указано: `delete(String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)`. Удалять запаписи удалось лишь таким образом:         `mDatabase.delete(FAVORITE_TABLE_NAME, MOVIE_ID + " = " + movie.getId(), null);`